# Execute a .run file on server

Tags: system-installation

I have a .run file that installed a diaspora instance on on my pc to local host.
Can I put that file on a remote Azure server and execute it making it available on the web?

Comment: That depends on the contents of the file. But I would assume: no, not without configuring it.

Comment: Feared it was so but hoped it could be done. Thank you for responding